# Types of Top down parsers

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, recursive-descent

I want to clearly classify top down parsers. After reading lot of resources, i am connecting the dots.
I concluded following -
There are 2 types of top down parsers -

1. One that uses backtracking
2. Another that doesn't use backtracking (also called predictive parsers)

Now, each of this can be of 2 types based on how we implement them.
If we implement them using recursion then its recursive descent parser, or, otherwise If we implement them using explicit stack then it is non recursive parser.

Hence there are 4 types of top down parsers-

1. Backtrack + recursive implementation (Recursive descent with backtrack)
2. Back track + stack implementation
3. No Backtrack + recursive implementation (Recursive descent without backtrack)
4. No Back track + stack implementation

Slide 8 [here](https://cs.rit.edu/%7Ehh/teaching/_media/cc18/lectures/lect12/main.pdf) says that predictive parser can be implemented in 2 ways.
But I am not able to verify if i am correct about parsers with backtracking too.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) says that " recursive descent parser is a kind of top-down parser built from a set of mutually recursive procedures (or a **non-recursive equivalent**) .... "
Which means recursive descent parsers can be implemented in non-recursive way too. Which i am not able to understand.

Please check my understanding about type of top down parser and also what does wikipedia entry means about non-recursive equivalent of recursive descent parsers.

Comment: *Any* recursive algorithm can be written using an explicit stack. If you think about it, even if you write the algorithm using recursive calls, at some level those recursive calls are being implemented at runtime using an explicit stack. So *how* you implement the recursion is independent of the algorithm, which is the same in both cases. (The recursive implementation is usually easier to read, and the non-recursive implementation is usually less safe, because most languages don't let you check for stack overflow. But those are also implementation details.)

Comment: yes i understand recursion vs iterative algorithms. For every recursion, theoretically there is iterative program. But It does not answer my question.

Comment: I don't know what your question is, exactly, but you say "Which means recursive descent parsers can be implemented in non-recursive way too. Which i am not able to understand." I was trying to help you understand it. I'm not saying that there is a different iterative algorithm. It's the same algorithm, and it is a recursive algorithm. It just happens that the recursion is implemented with an explicit stack. In other words, the essence of recursion is not that "a function calls itself" but rather that the algorithm proceeds by breaking a problem down into smaller instances of the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point about recursion. Kindly help me to classify top-down parses. Can I classify them in 4 ways ? (as I wrote). 2 ways based on backtrack and further 2 ways based on implementation.

Comment: You can classify them however you want to, but I don't think there is a precise or even useful division between "recursive" and "not recursive", in the way that you seem to want there to be. Backtracking clearly makes a difference; parsers which permit backtracking are objectively different from left-to-right bounded lookahead parsers. But those aren't all the possibilities, even within the somewhat murky territory of "top-down" parsers. You would also need to include PEG/packrat parsers, the somewhat-related LR(*) parsing (a la Antlr), and possibly even GLL, which is basically topdown.

Comment: And that's without even scratching the surface. Where might you colocate parser combinators, for example? Is it an algorithmic difference, or just a different programming style? (I don't know the answer to that question.) Most real-world parsers don't really conform tightly to any theoretical model, because it's too easy to use the power of a Turing-complete programming language to sidestep the limitations of a formal theory when its convenient to do so, and it almost always is.... This is why I didn't attempt an answer to your question in the first place.